# How to disable Neptune callback in transformers trainer runs?

Tags: python, pytorch, callback, huggingface-transformers, neptune

After installing [Neptune.ai](https://docs.neptune.ai/) for occasional ML experiments logging, it became included by default into the list of callbacks in all transformers.trainer runs. As a result, it requires proper initialisation with token or else throws `NeptuneMissingConfiguration` error, demanding token and project name.
This is really annoying, I'd prefer Neptune callback to limit itself to warning or just have it disabled if no token is provided.
Unfortunately there is no obvious way to disable this callback, short of uninstalling Neptune.ai altogether. The doc page at https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/callback states that this callback is enabled by default and gives no way to disable it (unlike some other callbacks that can be disabled by environment variable).

Question: how to disable Neptune callback on per run basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Neptune is included is because the default value of `report_to` in `TrainingArguments` is `"all"`, which implicitly includes all installed loggers from the officially supported list of loggers. You should either uninstall Neptune from the environment you use for the project, or pass `report_to="none"` to the `TrainingArguments` instance you use to initialize the `Trainer` (n.b.: that's the string literal `"none"`, NOT a Python `None`).

The other answers here, including the accepted answer, are either poor workarounds for this problem, or simply do not work at all. The proper way to handle this issue is as above.

Comment: you may be correct. I just cant test this fast. Switched to W&B.

Comment: @PoeDator The same applies to wandb FYI. It will be included by default by `Trainer` if installed into the working environment, unless you set `report_to` to `"none"`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this piece of code after `trainer` initialization helps:

```
for cb in trainer.callback_handler.callbacks:
    if isinstance(cb, transformers.integrations.NeptuneCallback):
        trainer.callback_handler.remove_callback(cb)
```

Still it would be good if Transformers or Neptune team provided more flexibility with this callback.

Comment: Not a good answer. The reason Neptune is included is because the default value of `report_to` in `TrainingArguments` is `all`, which implicitly includes all installed loggers from the officially supported list of loggers. See my response for the proper workaround.

Answer (score -1):

To disable Neptune callback in transformers trainer runs, you can pass the --no-neptune flag to the trainer.train() function.

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    no_neptune=True
)
trainer.train()
```

Comment: this would be a nice solution, but it does not work. there is no such argument in trainer. Also nothing like this in docs. transformers version='4.24.0'